# Groovy DSL with Java

Tags: java, groovy, dsl

It has been a couple of days since I started with Groovy. But with all the reading and surfing, I haven't quite been able to figure out how to accomplish what I have in mind. So, please excuse me as a beginner. Would be much grateful for your help, as always.

**What I want to achieve is this**: I have a Java class, say `ServiceClass` that has some methods (`getMethod()`, `postMethod()` etc) to make some REST GET/POST requests (on its own, it works fine). Now, I want to expose a DSL so that the end-user may just say something like: `callService ServiceClass method getMethod` and I have the execution of `ServiceClass.getMethod()`

What I have been trying so far is this: I got a `userCommand` file placed somewhere, that for now just reads: `callService ServiceClass`

I have a `sample.groovy` that just does this now:

```
class Sample {
    def srvc
    def callService(srvc) {
        this.srvc = srvc
        "Calling $srvc"
    }
}
```

I got an `integrator.groovy` file that has:

```
//necessary imports
class Integrator{
    def sample = new Sample()
    def binding = new Binding([
        sample:sample, 
        ServiceClass: new ServiceClass(), 
        callService:sample.&callService ])
    def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

    def runIt() {
        shell.evaluate("userCommand")
    }
}
```

And then to run it from my Java application, I am doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integator i = new Integrator()
    i.runIt();
}
```

But this is just not working. With the above syntax it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setVariable() on null object....

Could anyone please tell me how do I pass around parameters and create object instances?

Comment: What happens when you try? "not working" does not tell us what your problem is.

Comment: @bmargulies: have added the error message seen. Actually, am not even sure if the adopted approach is correct. So would like someone to guide me in how to have the whole thing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Consider the following `userCommand` file:

File `userCommand`:

```
callService ServiceClass getMethod
```

Which will be parsed by groovy as `callService(ServiceClass).getGetMethod()`. So you need a `getProperty` method which reroute the call to the correct method:

File `Dsl.groovy`:

```
class Dsl {
  static void main(args) {
      new Integrator().runIt()
  }
}

class DslDelegate {
    def service
    def callService(service) {
        this.service = service
        this
    }

    def getProperty(String prop) {
      if (prop == "getMethod") { service.getMethod() }
      else { throw new RuntimeException("Unrecognized property '$prop'") }
    }
}

class ServiceClass {
  def getMethod() { "serviceClass getMethod" }
}

class Integrator{
    def dslDelegate = new DslDelegate()
    def binding = new Binding([
        ServiceClass: new ServiceClass(), 
        callService:dslDelegate.&callService ])
    def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

    def runIt() {
        assert shell.evaluate(new File("userCommand")) == 
            "serviceClass getMethod"
    }
}
```

Note I renamed the `Sample` class, so it becomes a delegator to `ServiceClass`. Now it separates DSL/Service responsibilities.

You can do `callService ServiceClass method getMethod` too, but it requires more code.

Comment: :thank you, the code you suggested above does not throw any error but it does not really invoke 'callService' either. Have tried it but it does not print "Calling ServiceClass" :(

Comment: Actually, i got this to work by making the 'userCommand' file to have a '.groovy' extension. Actually was expecting the "userCommand" file to be just any text file; but probably it does not work like that. Now that i have got started, was wondering if you could please guide me in achieving the target. That is, now i want to have something like "callService (ServiceName:ServiceClass, MethodName:getMethod)' in my 'userCommand.groovy'. How do i translate it in my 'Integrator" so that in "callService" method i have "ServiceClass.getMethod()".

Comment: The above code should not print, but rather have a passing assert in the `runIt` method. Try adding a print after `this.srvc = srvc` and it shall work. My `userCommand` file doesn't have a groovy extension

Comment: just one more request Will, could you please help me find some material/guidance on method chaining in Groovy without using dots and parentheses? Have been looking around without much luck